# Why was Jack (Monkey) still Cursed in Pirates of the Caribbean?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest, the-curse-of-the-black-pearl

After watching *Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl*  yesterday, I decided to watch the sequel today. With the first still fresh in my mind, I noticed that Jack, the monkey, was still cursed from the Aztec gold, despite the fact that no one else was, and that the Curse had been lifted from everyone else (as far as I could tell and was implied).

Why is this? Am I missing something, or is there a bonified reason for him still carrying the curse?

Comment: @SQB: bonafide isn’t *bona fide*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the post-credits scene of *Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl*, Jack the monkey steals a piece of gold from the pile, cursing himself.

[image: you're a bad, bad monkey]

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I didn't realise that Pirates had post credit scenes :)

Comment: All of them do, and they're arguably some of the best moments from the films XD

Comment: I always wondered if some other poor pirate crew managed to find the chest and take the gold; would they be hunting the seas for a monkey?